# Wordpress maximum execution time exceeded

Tags: php, wordpress, timeout, advanced-custom-fields, execution

To keep things short, I have a WordPress multi site set up. One of the sites (out of seven total) has a lot of ACF created to accommodate the required data. It is currently sitting at over 160k (including all the revisions).

I have started to run into a lot of problems, including fields not saving and pages not updating because of "Maximum execution time exceeded".

What I have done so far is increase `max_execution_time` to 60s, `max_input_vars` to 5000 and `memory_limit` to 512M (in `php.ini` and `wp-config.php`). I'm still running into the execution timeouts and pages with a lot of fields take a really long time to update/load.

Is there anything else that could be holding things back? If it helps, it's hosted on DigitalOcean with 1GB CPU, 30GB SSD and 2TB transfer.

Comment: Did you also increase max_execution_time? BTW, I've run into this exact situation, with tons of ACF fields... when you really go to town with them, they can really bog things down. Never really came up with a great solution to that particular problem.

Comment: My mistake, I did change max_execution_time and not max_input_time as I previously wrote.

Comment: You could also refactor your code (not use ACF) and have it not time out.

Comment: Are you on a VPS or dedicated?

Comment: I was not the one who did the initial installation. Is there a way to tell from within DO?